# How can I use a map function, created by me, to print the values ​of an array

Tags: c++

I created this map function which takes a function as input, in my case the print function, and prints the values ​​of an array

```
    template<typename Data>
    void Vector<Data>::MapPreOrder(MapFunctor fun, void* par){
     for(unsigned long index = 0 ; index < Size; index++){
       fun(Elements[index], par);
     }
    }

    template<typename Data>
    void print( Data& data){
     std::cout << data<< '\n';
    }
```

in main, however, I don't know how to pass the function to the map function. I thought of doing this but it gives me errors

```
void* noParameter = nullptr;

    myVec.MapPreOrder(print(myVec[0]), noParameter);
```

Comment: How is the type `MapFunctor` defined?

Comment: `print(whatever)` is a function call that returns a particular value. The template parameter requires a value, which in this case would be a callable object. `&print<the_right_type>` should produce the requisite pointer.

Comment: @merlinND void MapPreOrder(MapFunctor, void*)

Comment: @Antonio - Your comment is a prototype that uses `MapFunctor`, but where's the actual definition fo r`MapFunctor`?

Comment: typedef std::function<void(Data&, void*)> MapFunctor;
@merlinND

Comment: @Antonio So can you see the problem? Your functor requires a function with two parameters, but you have a print function with only one parameter. You need to add the second parameter to your print function. Then you just do what Sam said.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `void *` is a C code, and not C++. I think it is much easier if you use the entire force of C++ (for this C++14 and higher) in order to make a much simpler code:

```
template<typename Data>
class Vector
{
// class code here...

    template <typename MapFunc, typename ... ParamTypes>
    void map_pre_order(MapFunc fun, ParamTypes ... par)
    {
        for(uint32_t index = 0 ; index < size; index++)
        {
            fun(elements[index], par...);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto print_func = [](const auto& data) { std::cout << data << "\n"; };
    constexpr auto print_func_with_params = [](const auto& data, const std::string& extra)
    {
        std::cout << data << extra;
    };

    Vector<int> vec{10};

    vec.map_pre_order(print_func);
    vec.map_pre_order(print_func_with_params, " extra \n");
}
```

In this code, I made `MapFunc` a template instead of defining it, and variadic template in order to pack all of the extra arguments for the function. This way, if you have a function with no extra arguments, you don't need to pass anything to it.

I have also used the `auto` specifier in the lambda, in order to mimic the "template" behavior, just in lambda (this is why C++14 is needed here).